# Primefaces 10+ Datatable how to get sorted column from SortEvent?

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

We are currently using Primefaces version 8 and I am working on migrating us to version 12.

In the migration guide [8.0 -> 10.0.0](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0), under DataTable, Breaking changes says this:

> SortEvent: sorted datatable value is no longer passed to this event,
> instead get the sorted value through your managed bean (e.g
> YourBean#list used as value expression)

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to pass the column being sorted as a value expression.

Here is what we currently have working using Primefaces 8 (simplified):

```
<p:dataTable id="searchResultsTable" 
    value="#{nameBackingBean.queryResults}"
    var="searchResultsRow" widgetVar="tableWidget"
    sortBy="#{searchResultsRow.name}" sortOrder="ascending">
    
    <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{nameBackingBean.sortedColumnSelected}" />
    
    <!-- Name -->
    <p:column headerText="Name"
        sortBy="#{searchResultsRow.name}">
        <h:outputText id="nameValue"
            value="#{searchResultsRow.name}" />
    </p:column>
    
    <!-- Age -->
    <p:column headerText="Age"
        sortBy="#{searchResultsRow.age}">
        <h:outputText id="ageValue"
            value="#{searchResultsRow.age}" />
    </p:column>
    
    ...
```

And here is the java backing bean method that is called when a sort is performed:

```
  public void sortedColumnSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
      if (null != event.getSource()){
         DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
         if(table != null && table.getSortColumn() != null){
            String headerText = table.getSortColumn().getHeaderText();
            String sortOrder = table.getSortOrder();
            
            if(headerText.equals("Name")){
               //we do something
            }else if (headerText.equals("Age")){
               //we do something else
            ...
```

The getSortColumn method is no longer available after Primefaces 8, so I am assuming I have to use some EL expression to figure out which column was sorted (based off of the sentence e.g. YourBean#list used as a value expression) and pass the value in like this...

```
<p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{nameBackingBean.sortedColumnSelected(el expression telling me what column was sorted)}" />
```

If anyone knows how to format the value expression to tell me which column was sorted, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course after I post this, I think I figured it out.

It looks like there is a method in DataTable called **getActiveSortMeta** which appears to hold the columns that are being sorted. The key in the map is the field being sorted. My DataTable only allows the sorting of one column at a time, so the map only contains one entry.

Here is my example code:

```
public void sortedColumnSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
  if (null != event.getSource()) {
     DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
     
     /* This map should contain the column that is being sorted. Since only
      * one column can be sorted at a time, there should only be one. */
     Map <String, SortMeta> sortMap = table.getActiveSortMeta();

     if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(sortMap)) {
     
        String fieldName = sortMap.keySet().iterator().next();

        SortMeta meta = sortMap.get(fieldName);
        String sortOrder = meta.getOrder().name();

        /* set the sort order so the report can display correctly. */
        setSortAscending(sortOrder.equals("ASCENDING"));

        if (fieldName.equals("name")) {
          //do something
        } else if (fieldName.equals("age")) {
          //do something else
        }
```

Hope this helps someone else. If you know of a different way of doing this, I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

As MrChris already stated, there is *DataTable#getActiveSortMeta*.
This can also be used with:

```
<p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{managedBean.onSort}" />
```

and some Bean named "managedBean":

```
public void onSort(SortEvent event) {
    var tbl = (DataTable) event.getSource();
    var activeSort = tbl.getActiveSortMeta();
    // ... whatever
}
```